# Proof of Centripetal Acceleration Angle $\theta$ is the same?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, vectors, rotational-kinematics

The book I am reading shows a proof of centripetal acceleration.

[image: Centripetal Acceleration Diagram]

It proceeds to say that *the linear velocity is always at a tangent to the radius, so the angle between $V_A$ and $V_B$ is also $\theta$*

This is what it shows next. [image: Proof Of Centripetal Acceleration]

I can't seem to understand why the angle $\theta$ is the same.

Can someone explain please why, because I don't understand the book explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The angle between the two velocity vectors is $x + x'$, where $x$ and $x'$ are the angles of the vectors with respect to a chord (the dashed line) of the circle. Now, as $ x + \alpha = \pi/2$ we have that $x = \pi/2 - \alpha$.

Similarly, $x' + \pi/2 + \alpha = \pi \Rightarrow x' = \pi/2 - \alpha$.

Thus, $$x + x' = \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha \right) + \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha \right) = \pi -2\alpha.$$

$\alpha$ is the angle appearing in the isosceles triangle so $2\alpha = \pi - \theta$ and therefore $$x+x' = \pi - (\pi - \theta) = \theta,$$ as required.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Draw a parallel line to V<sub>A</sub> on point B. Notice $\angle OBH = 90 ^\circ-\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$90+90+\theta+a = 360$ and $b+a=180 \Rightarrow b= \theta$